# Unsupported content type with GraphIql apollo engine

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm running apollo-server-express, and all works fine. I have 2 endpoints - 1 for graphiql (/graphql) and one for non-interactive (/client) queries (I know - they were called that before I started with apollo).

```
 app.use('/client', bodyParser.json() ,  
  (req, res,next) => {
    const context = { pool , apiKey:req.query.key , bidules };
    if (server.isAuthorized(context.apiKey)) {
      return graphqlExpress({
        schema: schema,
        context: context,
        tracing: true,
        cacheControl: {
          defaultMaxAge: 30,
        }
      }) (req,res,next); 
    }
    else {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.status(403)
      .send (JSON.stringify({
        errors:[ {message: "api key is unauthorized"} ]
      })); 
    }
  }
);

// endpoint for browser graphIQL
app.use('/graphql',  graphiqlExpress({ 
  endpointURL: '/client' 
}));


app.use("/schema", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.send(printSchema(schema));
});
```

But, when I introduce apollo engine

```
engine.listen({
  port: port,
  expressApp: fidserver.app,
  graphqlPaths: ['/graphql', '/client']
});
```

everything still works fine - except when I refresh graphiql  on the browser with the  query as parameters on the browser url.

Then I get this error

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Unsupported Content-Type from origin: text/html"}]}
```

Doing the same thing without apollo engine running does not cause an error. If run the query again, or refresh the browser without the query and variable parameters everything works just fine with or without Apollo Engine enabled.

When the error happens I can see from my server log that it's trying to return a react web page containing some javascript for decoding parameters from somewhere but I can't track down from where - it doesn't get as far as hitting any of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by the guys at Apollo. Here's the answer - I shouldn't have had my graphIQL end point mentioned in the engine.listen options.

Engine should only be placed between the client and the GraphQL server endpoint.  Try a config like this:

```
engine.listen({
  port: port,
  expressApp: fidserver.app,
  graphqlPaths: ['/client'] // removed "graphql"
});
```